# LazyLoading with NSURL Connenction

Tags: ios

I am loading images in tableview by using the below code.

[LazyTableImages](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html)

The problem is

when I tap on image then I go to detail view of that image by using service call(post method). 
In that servie call I got xml format. By using parsing I will get data.

But problem is when I click on back button it goes to mainView (lazyloading tableview). 
When I am doing continuously the app will be crash.

Please, give me solution for my above question

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have used that code and code work fine for me. Debug your code and find out on which line your app is crashing and post that part and error log here.

Comment: i don't know at which line the app will be crashed.i got low memory warning when i tap image then i will go to detail view then i back to mainview.i did the above operation continosly i got low memory waning

Comment: i got low memory warning when i tap image then i will go to detail view then i back to mainview.I did the above operation continuously i got low memory waning.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't try using a lazyload lib. I strongly recommend [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage). You only needs to add one line and done. Read the README, it's very simple.